# Visual Studio 2015 not able to locate custom report assembly

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I am getting this error in Visual Studio 2015 report project.  This project builds fine in VS2012.  I suspect VS2015 is not able to locate a custom assembly at compile time.  But I am not sure which all paths it is searching.

> Error     [rsErrorLoadingCodeModule] Error while loading code module:
>   ‘xxxx.Reports.SDK, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null’. Details: Could not load file or assembly
>   'xxxx.Reports.SDK, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

I have already deployed my custom assembly on these locations but it did not help.

```
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

- C:\Program    Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting
   Services\ReportServer\bin  

- C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin

- C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin
```

Please help me resolve this issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should deploy your custom assembly to the VS2015 Folder for private assemblies (in standard installations: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio **14.0**\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies"

Comment: For VS2015 this solution worked for me. Put your custom binaries in that folder.

Comment: This worked for me in ancient VS 2005 & SQL 2005 standard on Windows Server 2003 standard